# Consider the experiment of rolling two dice. If X =(second die−first die), then find the probability mass function of X.

Tags: probability

What should be the probability mass function for this question??

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write down all possible values of $X$ and find the probabilities for each of those events. First find the range of $X$. In this case the range will be $1-6 = -5$ to $6-1 = 5$. So PMF can be found as follows:
$$P(X<-5) = P(X>-5) = 0$$
$$P(X = -5) = P(die2 = 1)P(die1 = 6) = \frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{36}$$
$$P(X = -4) = P(die2 = 2)P(die1 = 6)+ P(die2 = 1)P(die1 = 5) = \frac{2}{36}$$
$$P(X = -3) = \frac{3}{36}$$ and so on

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: same distribution as sum, but shifted so that it is centered at zero.  $P(X=0)=6/36$, $P(X=\pm 1)=5/36$ each, ..., $P(X=\pm 5)=1/36$ each.

Answer (score 0):

Let A, B be the rolls of the first and second die, respectively, and $X=A-B$.

$\begin{matrix}
Rolls &A+B &Probability& A-B&Rolls\\
1,\textbf 1&2&\frac 1{36}&\textbf{-5}&1,6\\
1,\textbf2;2,\textbf1&3&\frac 2{36}&\textbf{-4}&1,5;2,6\\
1,\textbf3;2,\textbf2;3,\textbf1&4&\frac 3{36}&\textbf{-3}&1,4;2,5;3,6\\
...&...&...&...&...\\
6,\textbf4;5,\textbf5;4,\textbf6&10&\frac 3 {36}&\textbf{3}&4,1;5,2;6,3\\
6,\textbf5;5,\textbf6&11&\frac 2{36}&\textbf{4}&6,2;5,1\\
6,\textbf6&12&\frac 1{36}&\textbf{5}&6,1
\end{matrix}$

Notice that the pmf of $A-B$ follows a similar pattern as the pmf for $A+B$. In particular, the center is now at 0 (instead of 7), and the second dice now runs in the "opposite direction". The pmf is then, as stated in the quick answer, $P(A-B=\pm5)=\frac 1 {36} \text { each},...,P(A-B=\pm1)=\frac 5 {36} \text{ each},P(X=0)=\frac 6 {36}$.